# find rank of 2x2 array

Tags: java, arrays, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a 2d array that plays the role of a 2x2 matrix. How can I find the rank of that matrix. Until now I have this:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

int[][] A = new int[2][2];
int[][] B = new int[2][2];
int[][] C = new int[2][2];

System.out.println("Enter elements for matrix A : ");

for (int i=0 ; i < A.length ; i++)
{
    for  (int j=0 ; j < A[i].length ; j++)
    {
        A[i][j] = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Matrix A: ");
    for (int i=0 ; i < A.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(int j=0 ; j < A[i].length ; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(A[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I find the rank of that matrix (array)?.

Comment: What is the meaning of rank ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani [Rank (linear algebra)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra))

Comment: What have you tried? Because the code here is not related to finding the rank, it just populates and prints the matrix.

Comment: Well, it's 1 or 2. What is the condition that would make it a rank 1 matrix? check for that.

Comment: @SeanOwen - I think it could also be zero ...

Comment: True, if it's all 0. I had sort of guessed he wasn't interested in the degenerate case but that is right.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the rank of the matrix by converting the matrix to row-echelon form. The row-echelon form of your matrix will have the same rank as the matrix. The rank of the row-echelon form matrix is simply the total number of non-zero rows. In the 2x2 case you have here the calculations are very very simple. See this link for a more detailed explanation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Computation

A simpler crude approach that would be fast (since you only have 2x2 matrices) is to simply detect if one column of your matrix is a multiple of the other. This can be detected approximately by testing (to some numerical tolerance of your choice) whether or not these ratios are equal (using matrix notation, not integer zero based array indices)

```
 A(1,1)/A(1,2) == A(2,1)/A(2,2)
```

taking care with zero division as usual. If the ratios are equal, that suggests your columns are multiples of eachother and hence the matrix is not full rank (so is either 1 or 0). If all matrix elements are zero, then the rank is zero.

If this is too crude for your needs, use the Gaussian elimination approach suggested in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

@Sean Owen: the rank could also be 0.